# Why am I encouraged to download jQuery locally instead of using a CDN?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What are the benefits to downloading a 3rd party library like jQuery locally instead of using a CDN or code repository like Github?

Some answers:

1. your project won't need to be online to run. If the third party library you link to is not cached
   ( temporarily stored ) in your browser then you will have to be online to grab a new copy.
   For example when hard refreshing a webpage with CTRL(CMD)-SHIFT-R.
2. Fewer bugs / More control. If you have a local copy of a third-party library, there is a chance that the source may be updated to a new breaking version ( normally not, as URLS are versioned, linking to different versions), introducing bugs into the rest of your code.
   If you explicitly control which version you have by keeping it local and updating it manually, you can keep track of version changes and check for bugs before updating.

EDIT: I asked this question in my first days of programming. Apologies for the poor original quality.

Comment: Download jQuery... to host on your web server? To your second question: [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: [related](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/139372/referencing-external-javascript-vs-hosting-my-own-copy/139380#139380)

Comment: http://try.jquery.com | http://learn.jquery.com | http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one reason, to run the scripts without needing to be connected on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download it in order to include it in your project. otherwise you can use the google hosted library here

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```